# Several pairwise t-tests in R (with Bonferroni correction)

Tags: r, statistics, t-test, bonferroni

I'm running an experiment where participants have to rate several different scents on different dimensions. Below is an example of my data. In other words, participants are rating scent A on four dimensions, then they evaluate scent B on the same dimensions, followed by scent C.

```
A_pleasant <-c(4,5,4,6,7,5,5,4,4,1,5,6)
A_complex <-c(1,1,2,3,2,2,1,2,1,4,2,3)
A_familiar <-c(7,7,7,6,7,5,7,5,7,5,5,2)
A_relaxing <-c(4,5,4,6,3,4,2,4,5,2,5,5)
B_pleasant <-c(4,5,7,6,7,5,5,7,7,2,5,6)
B_complex <-c(3,3,3,2,3,5,1,3,2,3,3,3)
B_familiar <-c(6,6,6,4,3,4,3,4,7,6,5,6)
B_relaxing <-c(4,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,5,2,5,2)
C_pleasant <-c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,4,1,2,1)
C_complex <-c(2,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,2,1,3)
C_familiar <-c(1,1,2,1,4,3,4,2,1,2,1,2)
C_relaxing <-c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)

df <-data.frame(A_pleasant,A_complex,A_familiar,A_relaxing,B_pleasant,B_complex,B_familiar,B_relaxing,C_pleasant,C_complex,C_familiar,C_relaxing)
df
```

I'm interested in running within-subjects t-tests, with Bonferroni corrections for multiple comparisons, to see where the differences lie between these scents. E.g., I want to know which scents are significantly different in terms of pleasantness.

How can I run this on R? Is my data set up appropriately, or do I need to group the variables somehow?

Thank you!

I've used t.test on R but I'm not sure how to run this test with several samples, nor how to correct for multiple comparisons.

Comment: `with(stack(df), pairwise.t.test(values, ind, p.adjust.method = 'bonf'))`